# Cannot send values of multiple inputs with same name

Tags: php, html, input

I have inputs with same name( `institution[]` ) in a form with method POST. I am trying to use these inputs by `$_POST["institution"]` but that returns a string instead of an array. What is the problem?

HTML Code:

```
<table class='p1'>
<tr>
    <td>Üniversite/Kurum</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='institution[]' maxlength='150' onkeypress='return isGoodKey(event)' value=''></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Program</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='program[]' maxlength='150' onkeypress='return isGoodKey(event)' value=''></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Ülke</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='country[]' maxlength='40' onkeypress='return isGoodKey(event)' value=''></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Şehir</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='city[]' maxlength='100' onkeypress='return isGoodKey(event)' value=''></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class='p1'>
    <tr>
    <td>Üniversite/Kurum</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='institution[]' maxlength='150' onkeypress='return isGoodKey(event)' value=''></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Program</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='program[]' maxlength='150' onkeypress='return isGoodKey(event)' value=''></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Ülke</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='country[]' maxlength='40' onkeypress='return isGoodKey(event)' value=''></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Şehir</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='city[]' maxlength='100' onkeypress='return isGoodKey(event)' value=''></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

PHP Code:

```
$institution[] = $_POST['institution'];
$program[] = $_POST['program'];
$country[] = $_POST['country'];
$city[] = $_POST['city'];
```

And this is what I get when I `var_dump($_POST)`:

```
array(6) { ["camp_count"]=> string(1) "2" ["institution"]=> string(3) "mom" ["program"]=> string(3) "dad" ["country"]=> string(0) "" ["city"]=> string(0) "" ["submit"]=> string(5) "Devam" }
```

**UPDATE:**
Here is the `isGoodKey(event)` function

```
function isGoodKey(evt){
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
  var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
  var charTyped = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
  var myChars = new Array("A","B","C","Ç","D","E","F","G","Ğ","H","I","İ","J","K","L","M","N","O","Ö","P","R","S","Ş","T","U","Ü","V","Y","Z","1","2","3","4","4","5","6","7","8","9","0",",",":",".","/","a","b","c","ç","d","e","f","g","ğ","h","ı","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","ö","p","r","s","ş","t","u","ü","v","y","z","Q","q","W","w","x","X"," ","@"); 
  if((myChars.indexOf(charTyped) != -1)||charCode==8){
      return true;
  }else{
      alert("Bu alana kullandığınız karakterlerle giriş yapılamaz!");
      return false;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Here you can find the whole document:
http://codepad.org/WgJzApco

**UPDATE:**
OK, thats only because of my stupidity. I was adding the table after the first with js, and the names in js wasn't with array parenthesis( [ ] ). No problem now.

Comment: Remove the '[]' from your variable names?

Comment: @mickzer unfortunately, that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The names in my actual code wasn't really the same. When I made all the names same and with [], everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP you are already receiving them as array, so don't put them in the array again. Try this:

```
$institution = $_POST['institution'];
$program = $_POST['program'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
```

Comment: That was what I did at first, but that didn't work. As far as I understand, instead of making an array and sending the inputs, browser sends only the last one of them. But I cannot see why.

Comment: Could you post your `var_dump($_POST)` and not the `var_dump($_POST[])`

Comment: That is actually my typo, the one I posted is it. I wanted to write var_dump($_POST), correcting it now.

Comment: Ok, I just ran your code without `onkeypress='return isGoodKey(event)'` and it is sending the values as arrays. Now could you please double check your form method is post and also copy the code for `isGoodKey(event)` to see if there is any code that does something that it shouldn't. Also where is `camp_count` coming from?

Comment: my form method is post, I checked. isGoodKey is a function written by my friend which block some chars to be inserted to textbox, I will copy the code in my question. And `camp_count` is coming from an hidden input in the same form. There is no problem with that.

Comment: JS is ok. Your code runs fine and I can't replicate your problem. Reading your code again, I noticed you are duplicating the same input twice (the table block is printed twice), is that how it is in your real code?

Comment: Yes, exactly. (and sometimes more than two)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the square brackets here.

$_POST['institution'] holds an array. So you don't try and put that array into another array.

If you had:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3);
```

And you wanted to copy the contents of $array to another variable $array2, you would use:

```
$array2 = $array;
```

So copying an array from $_POST['index'] is the exact same.

Change your php to:

```
$institution = $_POST['institution'];
$program = $_POST['program'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in trying to use `[]` with text inputs. Try forcing the index in the variable name, like this:

```
<input type="text" name="institution[0]" />
...
<input type="text" name="institution[1]" />
```

**UPDATE**
I just ran this code and it worked without issue.

```
<?php

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST);

?>
<html>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="institution[]" value="1" />
        <input type="text" name="institution[]" value="2" />
        <input type="text" name="institution[]" value="3" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</html>

Array
(
    [institution] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )
)
```

What are your version of PHP and Apache?

Comment: Php 5.5.9, Apache 2.4.7

Comment: Taking a shot in the dark; what is your DOCTYPE declaration?

Comment: <!doctype html> , here you can find the whole document: http://codepad.org/WgJzApco